# Playing with Classes, Objects and Constructors / C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a calculator application using c++, using a class and a constructor just to practice. I created a class including 4 functions, each for each operator. In the main function I used an if statement to choose the mathematical operator, a vector to store the inputs of the user. This vector is going to be carried out to the constructor of the class and to the functions respectively.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Calc {
public:
    Calc(vector<int> vec)
    {
        numbers = vec;
    }

    int add()
    {
        int total = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 1; i <= numbers.size(); i++)
        {
            total += numbers[i];
        }

        return total;
    }

    int sub()
    {
        int total = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 1; i <= numbers.size(); i++)
        {
            total = total - numbers[i];
        }

        return total;
    }

    int mul()
    {
        int total = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 1; i <= numbers.size(); i++)
        {
            total = total * numbers[i];
        }

        return total;
    }

    int div()
    {
        int total = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 1; i <= numbers.size(); i++)
        {
            total += numbers[i];
        }

        return total;
    }

private:
    vector<int> numbers;

};

int main()
{
    int operation;
    cout << "\nEnter the digit that corresponds to the wanted operation:\n1. +\n2. -\n3. *\n4. /\n\n";
    cin >> operation;

    if (operation != 1 && operation != 2 && operation != 3 && operation != 4)
    {
        cout << "Invalid entry.";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "\nEnter the numbers followed with a 0 to get the result: ";

    int num = 1;
    vector<int> nums;

    while (num != 0)
    {
        cin >> num;
        nums.push_back(num);
    }

    Calc Inputs(nums);

    if (operation == 1)
    {
        cout << Inputs.add();
    }

    else if (operation == 2)
    {
        cout << Inputs.sub();
    }

    else if (operation == 3)
    {
        cout << Inputs.mul();
    }

    else if (operation == 4)
    {
        cout << Inputs.div();
    }

    else 
    {
        cout << "Invalid entry.";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The prgoram runs perfectly until I enter the numbers to calculate. Can anyone help me with finding out whats wrong with my code.

Comment: Your ending code tags need to be on a separate line. ... what happens when you enter the numbers?

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= numbers.size(); i++)` should be `for (int i = 1; i < numbers.size(); i++)`. C++ uses 0-indexing (`i` should be initialized to 0 when you don't use first item outside of the loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ indexes start by 0 and go up to `numbers.size() - 1`.

```
numbers[numbers.size()]
```

will access the element *after* the last entry of the vector, aka. is out of bounds access and causes undefined behaviour, which can result in a segmentation fault.

Correct would be

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) { total += numbers[i]; }
```

or let the compiler do the hard work and use range based loops:

```
for(auto i : numbers) { total += i; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did the following correction: `int total = numbers[0];
  for (int i = 1; i <= numbers.size() - 1; i++)` . I initialized my total variable with the value of the first element of the vector "numbers" to avoid including any outlier values in the calculation. And hence, I started the loop index with 1 and not with 0.